# Split Local Repository Maven Resolver API

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I am a user of the Maven Resolver API and have a hard time finding any documentation regarding the implementation/classes of the API to use when
implementing "*Split Local Repository*" and to "*differentiate between cached and locally installed artifacts*" as described in https://maven.apache.org/resolver/local-repository.html.

The use case I am trying to implement is a Java client application downloading artifacts with 2 Local repositories.
One pre-loaded read-only cache, and another where remotely downloaded artifacts, not found in the read-only cache, are installed.

First of all I wonder if the described use case even possible to solve with current version of the Resolver API?
In that case are there any code (java) examples for this. May be some JUBIT tests in the Maven Artifact Resolver code repository?

I am currently using resolver **1.8.2** but I am happy to upgrade to the latest (**1.9.2**).
The following is the code I am currently using to initiate my Session/LocalRepository

```
 DefaultRepositorySystemSession session = MavenRepositorySystemUtils.newSession();

 LocalRepository localRepo = new LocalRepository(repoBaseDir);
 session.setLocalRepositoryManager(system.newLocalRepositoryManager(session, localRepo));
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems [ChainedLocalRepositoryManager](https://github.com/apache/maven-resolver/blob/master/maven-resolver-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/util/repository/ChainedLocalRepositoryManager.java) is what you actually need:

```
DefaultRepositorySystemSession session = MavenRepositorySystemUtils.newSession();

LocalRepositoryManager cacheRepository = system.newLocalRepositoryManager(
        session, 
        new LocalRepository(cacheRepositoryDir)
);

LocalRepositoryManager rwRepository = system.newLocalRepositoryManager(
        session, 
        new LocalRepository(rwRepository)
);

LocalRepositoryManager chainedRepository = new ChainedLocalRepositoryManager(
        rwRepository, 
        Collections.singletonList(cacheRepository), 
        true
);


session.setLocalRepositoryManager(chainedRepository);
```